# Displaying a quote from the first post using Jekyll

Tags: liquid, jekyll

I'm trying to set up Jekyll so that a quote from the first post in the list of posts is displayed in a sidebar, but I can't quite work out how to do it. I have the quote text defined as a `quote` variable within the YML Front Matter in each post's Markdown.

This is the relevant extract from my **default.html**:

```
<div id="content">
  {{ content }}
</div>    
<div id="sidebar">
  <blockquote>{{ page.quote }}</blockquote>
</div>
```

And this is my **index.html**:

```
---
layout: default
quote: ** Can a variable referencing the first post go here? **
---
{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
  <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
  <div class="post">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much experimentation, I was able to solve the problem using this Liquid snippet within **default.html**:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <blockquote>
  {% if page.quote %}
    {{ page.quote }}
  {% else %}
    {{ site.posts.first.quote }}
  {% endif %}
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
  {% if forloop.index0 == 0 %}
    {% assign quote = post.quote %}
  {% endif %}

  <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
  <div class="post">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and in **default.html**

```
<div id="content">
  {{ content }}
</div>    
<div id="sidebar">
  <blockquote>{{ quote }}</blockquote>
</div>
```

I don't think you can store references in the YML matter but this should get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work unfortunately. It looks like the variable assigned to isn't in scope from within the **default.html** file.

Comment: I've used this technique before so I am a bit surprised. Do you still have the `quote` in the YML block? You can try changing `page.quote` to `quote`.

Comment: No I don't have the `quote` in the YML block. Should I have?

Comment: It seems that you have to have `quote` defined in the YML Front Matter within **index.html** in order for it to be displayed within the **default.html** file.